# What determines when to use "have" or "has" when you list differing items?

Tags: grammar

Example **A**:

> Many eggs, baskets and basic food have been lost in the storm.

Example **B**:

> Many eggs, baskets and basic food has been lost in the storm.

Basically, I'm wondering what determines when you are supposed to use "has" or "have" when all the "items" listed prior to it are not of the same, um, "pluralis/singularis" form.

I'm not asking how to re-structure the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

'Has"' is the third person singular form of the present tense of the verb 'to have'. 'Have' is the present tense for all other persons (except the redundant second person singular). This includes the third person plural.

If you are discussing one thing then 'has' is correct, otherwise it's 'have'. For example

> "Many eggs *have* been lost in the storm" (many eggs, plural)

> "My basket and umbrella *have* been lost in the storm" (two single items, plural) but

> "My shed *has* been damaged in the storm (one shed, singular).

However we would say

> "Much basic food *has* been lost in the storm" ('basic food' is a *mass noun* and is treated as singular).

Having said that we would say

> "Many basic food *items have* been lost in the storm" (many *items*, plural)

This is my answer but I suspect that your question might be migrated to English Language Learners because it is very basic.